# Can we tell the difference types of recession?

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion

Because of the the Hubble red shift pattern, Cosmologist generally assume that space is expanding. They assume this is a fact because of the observed redshifts and GR says it can be so. But how can we tell the difference between two objects receding from:

1. sitting "stationary" in expanding space, or
2. moving apart through space?

Comment: That first sentence is a little backwards. Hubble's redshift measurements of Type Ia supernovae showed that the universe was expanding (as did the work of [Perlmutter, Schmidt, & Riess](http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/2011/)), so cosmologists have accepted it due to the empirical evidence.

Comment: There, i cut and pasted it to reverse the grammar. Or should i say, reversed the grammar did I, by cut and paste. Gotta love Yoda!

Comment: The question is: HOW CAN WE TELL THE DIFFERENCE?

Comment: Please stop shouting. We can read your request just fine in the usual case.

Comment: oops sorry @dmckee. i'm new.

Comment: If you were to pick an individual galaxy in isolation that appeared to be moving with respect to us then no measurement can distinguish between those two cases you've presented.

Answer (score 2):

I think the quick answer to your question is not really, no.  There would be no visible difference.   What we observe from a far away object is only light coming from or reflecting off the object.   The light from a distant star or galaxy, for example would be red-shifted in both scenarios, expanding space or moving away.   The observed red shifted light wouldn't tell you which of the 2 scenarios it was.

To take it back a step, if galaxies were just floating around in space - kind of tossed about like dots on a Jackson Pollack painting - moving any which way in any which direction, you couldn't learn much about the early universe by studying the movement of randomly tossed about galaxies.   It's because galaxies were discovered to be flying apart in a very neat and measurable way that lead to the rather neat and tidy big bang theory.  It's really no different than running the clock backwards and you can figure out about when the galaxies were pretty much together - it doesn't work as well with where, but you can calculate the when based on the consistency of Hubble's observations and discovery.

Now - classical big bang theory, and if you take the point of view of an observer, you would expect the galaxy that's 8 billion light years away should be moving twice as fast away from you as the galaxy 4 billion light years away - pretty simple, and when you add gravity, the rate of expansion should be slowing down.

So - from the point of view of the observer, the galaxy 8 billion light years away, what you see is light that left that galaxy 8 billion years ago, and 4 billion light years away, 4 billion years ago, and because gravity should be slowing expansion, you would expect your observation to of the 4 billion years away galaxy to have slowed down a little and be traveling a bit less than half as fast as your observations of the 8 billion light year away galaxy.

That's what everyone expected, but when they got good enough to measure this with accuracy, the results were the opposite.   The galaxy 4 billion light years away was to our observation, traveling a bit more than half the speed away from us as the Galaxy 8 billion light years away. - so, que twilight zone music.   This wasn't what they expected and it suggests that there was (and still is) an expansion force that pushes galaxies apart faster than gravity attracts them together.    That's how expansion of space was observed, but it took measuring many galaxies and comparing the speed in relation to us from us from a number of different distances.   It's because the closer galaxies are moving faster than predicted that lead scientists to the "space expands" theory.   So, that is an observable difference that was actually observed, but it's only observable by measuring quite a few galaxies at different distances and far enough away that big bang expansion is the primary factor in relative velocity.  We couldn't use Andromeda for example as the Milky way and Andromeda are close enough that gravity is pulling our 2 galaxies towards each other, likewise we couldn't use stars in our galaxy as the galactic orbit is the primary factor in relative velocity.  You need a number of far away galaxies to measure this kind of thing.

So, there's probobly not a way to tell the difference by observing a single object, as with your example of 2 objects, unless, you took measurements of the single object from 2 observation points at different distances, but that would be 3 objects.  In that scenario, it's maybe possible.   But the expansion of space is probobly very difficult to measure directly.  We see it only by looking a few billion years in the past/a few billion light years away and making careful comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Another argument supporting the expansion of space itself is that the movement described by userLTK is observed to happen no matter in which direction we look. When we assume that galaxies are moving through space that would put us at a very special point in space, i.e. the one from which everything else is moving away. Assuming an expanding space requires no such special treatment, as we would observe the same expansion no matter where we are in the universe.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation 1 naturally explains Hubble's law - that more distant objects appear to be moving away from us at a greater velocity. To demonstrate - I recommend constructing a 1D universe consisting of dots (galaxies) placed on a line and separated by 0.5cm. Now draw (underneath), the "Universe" a billion years later, but let the space between the "galaxies" expand to 1cm. Now draw yet another "universe" 2 billion years later, where the space has expanded to 1.5cm (i.e a uniform expansion with no acceleration) and so-on. Now pick a galaxy to represent where you are (any one, it doesn't matter!) and see what recession speed you would estimate for galaxies at different distances from you. Hey presto - Hubble's law.

Explanation 2 does not *explain* Hubble's law, it would need an *ad hoc* relationship between velocity and distance. Further, as far as we can tell, on large scales the expansion is isotropic and homogeneous, which would not be the case if galaxies were expanding away from a point in (fixed) space.

Other less direct evidence would include how you would actually construct the structure in the universe to start with if there was no expansion. The expansion of space reduces the density of both matter and energy and is an essential component of structure formation models.

The properties of the cosmic microwave background follow naturally from an expanding space model. The alternative would be to surround the universe with a sphere of opaque material expanding at extremely high speeds. The fact that the CMB is almost identical in all directions would then need us to be close to some central point.

Connected with this is the observation of evolution in the universe - e.g. there are few quasars in the immediate vicinity, but lots at redshifts of $z=2$. In explanation 2 you would have to have us near the centre of expansion in addition to the required temporal evolution.

All these bits and pieces rely on being able to measure more than just the redshift of a single galaxy. If that is *all* you have then I don't think there is an observational test.